# XML not being displayed as intended

Tags: android, xml

So I am working on  a message view for a simple SMS/GCM application.

my XML is written as follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="jp.mcs.smsmessanger.MainActivity">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button">
</ListView>

<TextView android:id="@+id/message_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false" />

<Button android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/list" />

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/sending"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button" />
```

Edit: Here is the Adapter class

```
public class ConversationAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Message> {

public ConversationAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Message> messages){
    super(context, 0, messages);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    //get the data for this position
    Message message = getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.convo_layout, parent, false);
    }

    TextView message_body = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_body);

    message_body.setText(message.message);
    return convertView;

}//end getView
```

}

According to the preview, it should be coming out like this:

[image: XML Preview]

However, when I run the application I am getting the EditText and Button with every single message in the view.

The data is being served from a SQLite DB, and it is using a custom Message model.

Is there anything wrong with my formatting that is causing the EditText and Button to repeat?

Comment: Each row in the listview is determined by your custom adapter. please post  it and the row view layout of each row

Comment: @Boss Ok, I just included the adapter class, but I only have my TextView included in it. Sorry I am new to Android.

Comment: what is your R.layout.convo_layout

Comment: @KaranMer convo_layout.xml is the XML code above

Comment: as you are inflating that layout and it have edit text and button it will display edittext and button

Comment: design a simple xml containing only textview and inflate that xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two layouts when you are using custom adapter.

one is for placing your listview and other views.

one is for inflating in the adapter.

Your problem is that you are using same layout for both operations.

You may not need a custom adapter for showing a single text in each view.
remove your custom adapter and try this code in your activity.

```
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Message msg : messages) {
            list.add(message.message);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        yourListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And if you still need a custom adapter create a layout which contains a single `TextView` and inflate that layout in the adapter.

Comment: Yes I was going the custom route in case I wanted to edit the view later. Thanks a lot!